# Using named parameter only when passing integer

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, sqlanywhere

Currently I'm trying to work with `Named Parameters` using `SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere 12` with dapper. The following codes runs correctly:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Str1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Str2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SAConnection connection = new SAConnection("..."))
        {
            connection.Open();

            Test test = connection.Query<Test>("SELECT :Str1 as Str1, :Str2 as Str2",
                new Test() { Str1 = 35, Str2 = "42" }).FirstOrDefault();                    

            Console.WriteLine($"Str1: {test.Str1} | Str2: {test.Str2}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But when i change `Str2 = "42"` to some `string`, than i get the following exception:

> Cast 42a to integer not possible

This exception is thrown when I'm using the following code:

```
Test test = connection.Query<Test>("SELECT :Str1 as Str1, :Str2 as Str2",
new Test() { Str1 = 35, Str2 = "42a" }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there some known issue? This should work correctly, cause i just want to pass a string around.

*Edit*

Stack trace:

> iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException (0x80004005): Umwandeln von '42a' auf integer nicht möglich
>      bei iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SACommand._ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior commandBehavior, Boolean isExecuteScalar, Boolean isBeginExecuteReader)
>      bei iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SACommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      bei System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>      bei Dapper.SqlMapper.d__61`1.MoveNext()
>      bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      bei Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType)
>      bei DapperSqlAnywhere.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users....\DapperSqlAnywhere\Program.cs:Zeile 35.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: In your `Test`, what type is the parameter `Str2` set to?

Comment: @Draken it is always a string/varchar. I'll post the complete stack trace as soon as I'm at home

Comment: Isn't there a FROM clause missing in your SQL statement?

Comment: @DocBrown no, thats just for providing a simple example. This query is valid and will returne exactly one row with two columns. For example: `SELECT 123 as Str1, 'hello' as Str2` Will return one row with (`123 | hello`)

Comment: Is the effect the same if you change the order i.e. `SELECT :Str2 as Str2, :Str1 as Str1`? Did you try to use CAST/CONVERT i.e.: `SELECT :Str1 as Str1, CAST(:Str2 AS Varchar(100)) as Str2`? I don't know SQLAnywhere so the syntax of my query might be wrong. I suspect that SQLAnywhere driver cannot infer data types of parameters if they are not explicitly specified.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer.Changing the order does not help. Casting as `varchar` works, but this should not be the solution, cause this will make even small queries with man parameters very large. And using `?` as placeholder also works without casting.

Comment: @MichałKomorowski you maybe gave me a good hint. I thing i got it. I Will create an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a great deal about SQLAnywhere but in your 1st select statement is being parsed as

```
SELECT 35 as Str1, 42 as Str2
```

which is fine because they're both integers
Your 2nd statement

```
SELECT 35 as Str1, 42a as Str2
```

should probably be

```
SELECT 35 as Str1, '42a' as Str2
```

So I'd try changing the code to

```
Test test = connection.Query<Test>("SELECT :Str1 as Str1, ':Str2' as Str2",
            new Test() { Str1 = 35, Str2 = "42" }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's not working, cause than ':Str2' will be the output. And not its value.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue because I do not have the SAConnection class but the point is that it's most likely your select statement that's failing because SQL does not recognise the value as a string without the single quotes. You need to find a way of parsing the statement with the single quotes.